# Does contiki-ng support UIP_REASSEMBLY?

Tags: contiki-ng

I can see in uipopt.h

```
#define UIP_REASSEMBLY (UIP_CONF_REASSEMBLY)
```

But no code about it in uIP stack.

It means no way to send ICMP/UDP with size > (MTU - header) from Host to node and between nodes.
Is this so ?

I have tried longer packets but it dosn't work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Contiki-NG does not have support for this configuration switch. Try enabling the `UIP_CONF_IPV6_REASSEMBLY` instead. We will remove the code referencing `UIP_CONF_REASSEMBLY` and `UIP_REASSEMBLY` in the future.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled 2 flags. #define UIP_CONF_REASSEMBLY                 1
#define UIP_CONF_IPV6_REASSEMBLY .            1. Linux host generate 2 fragments but Contiki is not recognized 2nd fragment and drop it [WARN: IPv6      ] incomplete IPv6 header received (8 bytes) . Here mentioned that it is not tested: https://docs.contiki-ng.org/en/master/_api/group__uipoptip.html. Or what is status if this feature and how to evaluate it properly ? MTU is 1500. And I would like to send UDP 2000 bytes from Linux Host to node.

Comment: I can't comment on these, and they look like a separate questions from this one. The comment mentioned that this feature is not extensively tested. In my 10+ years of using Contiki I have not ever encountered it. We use 6LoWPAN fragmentation and reassembly instead, typically.

Comment: 6LoWPAN fragment MTU ro smaller parts. IP fragmentation - big data to MTU size. It is not the same. According implementation ( a lot of code ) IP reassembly should work and long pings and UDPs can be send from Host to Node, but no idea why it dosn't work. Does someone is responsible for uIP stack in Contiki-NG ?

Comment: @Eugene it's uIPv6 stack in Contiki-NG. And the maintainers are collectively resposible.